# How does Python's multiprocessing module preform in comparison to Hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Essentially, in your experience if faced with a 'big(ish) data' problem how far can you get using Python's multiprocessing module when compared to something like Hadoop?

I ask because aside from proficiency in Python/SQL I am 'programming novice'. Hence Hadoop is pretty impenetrable to me at the moment, so hope to be able to get quite far using the multiprocessing module for many large data problems that come my way, at least until I can get my head around Hadoop.

EDIT for clarity: If I have a 4 core computer are there any advantages to using Hadoop on 4 nodes as opposed to the multiprocessing module?

Thanks.

Comment: How large is your data? How much computation are you doing? Hadoop is really only useful once you require more than one computer, it isn't so much if you just want to utilize multiple cores on the same computer.

Comment: I am talking about general differences. For example if I have a 4 core computer,is there an advantage to using Hadoop on 4 nodes as opposed to the multiprocessing module?

Comment: No, aside from any possible gains from having written your application in java vs python.

Comment: Thank you. So could it be said that Hadoop only becomes necessary when your problem requires more than the number of cores that your computer has?

Comment: Hadoop isn't for multicore computing. It's for data-parallel processing, i.e. distribution over disks rather than CPUs.

Comment: So it's more about computations that are too big for memory, rather than too complicated for one cpu?

Comment: It is more about datasets so large they cannot be stored sensibly on all the disks attached directly to one motherboard.